# R dynamic lists of lists

Tags: r, syntax

Hi I'm new to R and for a school project I'm trying to to create a lists of lists that I can access by index and append to. Something like

```
aList[1] = A, B, C

aList[1] returns [1] A, B, C

aList[1] += D

aList[1] returns [1] A, B, C, D

aList[2] = 1, 2, 3

aList[2] returns [2] 1, 2, 3

aList returns [1] A, B, C, D 
              [2] 1, 2, 3
```

However, I'm not sure if I'm using the right datatype (and definitely not the proper syntax) as everything I've tried just either makes a single index of a list or makes multiple indexes of one item.

This isn't the homework. This shouldn't even be an issue but I can't find a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lists in `R` are separate from vectors- each item in a vector can only be a basic type like a number or a string, while a list can contains vectors or other lists. It sounds like you want to create a list of vectors. This could be done as:

```
> aList = list(c("A", "B", "C"), c(1, 2, 3))
> aList[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C"
> aList[[1]] = c(aList[[1]], "D")
> aList[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
> aList[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
> aList
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

[[2]]
[1] 1 2 3
```

Note that you normally access a list using double brackets, like `[[1]]`. If you access a list using single brackets, you'll get a subset of the list:

```
[[1]]
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"
```

Which isn't what you want if you want to modify that item.

Comment: This was 90% of the way there. It was the brackets. Apparently I needed to do [[]] instead of [] when I attempted to append. Thank you!  EDIT: You completely answered it while I was writing comment. Thanks again.